# Stripe `AddressElement` is undefined

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using `stripe` to receive payments and I am following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/address-element/collect-addresses?platform=web) to get the `address` of the my buyers, but **the guide seems to be wrong wrong**:

- when importing `import {AddressElement} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';`, the library doesnt seem to have the `AddressElement` anywhere in there (I also searched manually for it) and `AddressElement` is `undefined`

Do you any idea if the guide is actually wrong?

Comment: I'm able to import AddressElement successfully as described in the doc. It's been added [here](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/pull/321). Could you check if you're on the latest version of `@stripe/react-stripe-js` and `@stripe/stripe-js`?

Comment: Address Element is available from [@stripe/react-stripe-js v1.11.0](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/releases/tag/v1.11.0) with [@stripe/stripe-js v1.37.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/releases/tag/v1.37.0)

Comment: Haha, yep, it was jus that - I had an older version of `@stripe/react-stripe-js`. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was easy to solve - I had an older version of `@stripe/react-stripe-js`. Installing the latest one solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

> AddressElement

Stripe now provides a

> BillingAddressFields

component that you can use to collect a customer's billing address.

Comment: I tried this and didnt work